# Catching output of oraclequery

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, pega

I am using the oraclequery component to run some database queries. I've successfully got the component connection to the Oracle db I want to query through the ConnectionString configuration. I have successfully tested a query that I wrote in the CommandText field. Now, how do I capture the output of the query?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I received an external response. Here is the recap of what was offered to me:

You create a windows form with the necessary components for your desired outcome (For this instance we have a button that initiates the automation/query and a dataGridView component that will display a dynamic output of query results)

1. Connect the query to the execute method.
2. Connect the query to the 'getTable' method.
3. Connect the getTable query to the dataGridView component (properties); Meanwhile connect the 'results' of getTable to dataTableProxy and also to the 'dataSource' of the dataGridView component.
4. Lastly, connect the dataGridView component to it's 'show' method.